# Show particular records at the bottom in webpage

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have drf website where i am showing the records of some sought on my website i have 4 different type of statuses on my webpage for records how do i show a particular status records related to the records at the bottom.

```
class MyListView(APIView):
```

Comment: You'll have to add some more context here. Your models would be a great start.

Comment: @Sahil Thats actually a big project mate it wouldn't make any sense as it is difficult to post all the code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
qs = Model.objects.extra(select={'bottom_status': "status = Closed"})
qs = qs.extra(order_by=['bottom_status'])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra